# smooth movement of markers on location change angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, marker, angular2-google-maps

i have used angular 2 google maps library in my porject to show google maps.
i have multiple markers in my map whose positions are changed frequently whenever a marker changes a position it jumps from one location to another location.i want to smooth movement of marker between two positions.
i have used https://github.com/terikon/marker-animate-unobtrusive this library in my js google map api and working fine but i tried to use the same library with this google map api but dont know how to do it.
i have included the cdn link in my html code and globally initialized the smoothing library but nothing is changed in my map.
is there any better approach to smooth markers movement?